# Ajax Modal : Return selected value to dropdown list into update form

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, modal-dialog

I have been searching everywhere on this website and tried many solutions but none worked for me ! My problem is the following :

I have 2 tables :

`TABLE INFO_STATUS (status_id, status_desc)`
and
`TABLE INFO_MARQUES (comp_id, comp_desc, comp_status(INT))`

I am linking `comp_status` and `status_id` so that the row in INFO_MARQUES will get the current status.

What I would like to do? (EDITED FROM HERE)
**2. get the current status value of `info_marques` located in `comp_status` automatically selected in the dropdown list when I open the update form**

**Example** I want to update this company :

```
comp_id : 15
comp_desc : WEISS
comp_status : 1
```

Assuming that in table info_status :

```
status_id = 1
status_desc = FOLLOW-UP
```

When I open the update form I want to see this :
[Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM0l8.jpg)

My Modal : **(WORKING)**

```
                        <select class="form-control" name="select_status">
                        <option value=''>Selectionner</option>
                    <?php 
try {
                    $user = new USER();
                    $output = array();
                    $stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM info_status");
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result=$stmt->fetchAll();

                    foreach($result as $row) {
                        echo '<option value='.$row["status_id"].'>'.$row["status_desc"].'</option>';
                    }
}
                    catch(PDOException $e) {
                    printf('Erreur MySQL %d : %s', $e->getCode(), $e->errorInfo[2]);
                    exit;

}
?>
                    </select>
```

My Ajax

```
$(document).on('click', '.update', function(){ 
        var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var array = [];
        $('select :selected').each(function(i,value)
        {
        array[i] = $(this).val();
        });     
        $.ajax({
            url:"partials/test/fetch_single.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{user_id:user_id},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#userModal').modal('show');
                $('#comp_name').val(data.comp_name);
                $('#comp_parent').val(data.comp_parent);

                $.each($('.select_status option'),function(a,b){

                if($(this).val()== data.comp_status){   
                $(this).attr('selected',true)
                }

                });

                $('.modal-title').text("Modifier un fichier client");
                $('#user_id').val(user_id);
                $('#user_uploaded_image').html(data.user_image);
                $('#action').val("Edit");
                $('#operation').val("Edit");

            }

        })
    });
```

then my PHP page : **(WORKING)**

```
if(isset($_POST["user_id"]))
{
    $output = array();
    $statement = $connection->prepare(
        "SELECT * 
FROM info_marques AS m 
LEFT JOIN info_status AS s 
ON s.status_id = m.comp_status 
WHERE m.id = '".$_POST["user_id"]."' 
LIMIT 1"
    );
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output["comp_name"] = $row["comp_name"];
        $output["comp_parent"] = $row["comp_parent"];
        $output["comp_status"] = $row["status_desc"];

    }

    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Cheers

Comment: Where is `#comp_name`, `#comp_parent`, etc?

Comment: I have only shown the modal part concerned by this issue, but these two are working fine in my modal.

Comment: `$('#select_status').val(data.comp_status);` does not work because `select` elements require `option` elements inside them. You need code that populates the `select` and sets `selected` to the one output from your AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, so I need to include that code into my php code and return a .html value? I will require to write 2 SQL queries then?

Comment: You will need a `SELECT` query to output to the modal before the AJAX request. On AJAX `success`, loop through the `option`s and set attribute selected if comp_status equal to option value.

Comment: @mulquin please kindly check my update above, it seems I am stuck somewhere, I feel I am this close to sort this out, a bit of help would be very welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that if you want to populate drop down or else select data based on your response, But if you want to select the data and you have options already in drop down, you can do this:

```
 $.each($('#select_status option'),function(a,b){

    if($(this).val() == data.comp_status){
              $(this).attr('selected',true)
    }

    });
```

But if you want to populate, you will have to append it using .append(). Do let me know if issue is something different and I may give you a solution.

As you are saying you need all the status and then show the current status. what i would suggest is use .done() method of ajax. It will come handy, like:

```
$("#select_status").prop('disabled',true)
$('#select_id').append('<option>Please wait... Fetching status</option>');
var status_options;
$.ajax({
 url:"your_page_for_all_status.php",
 success: function(e){
    //add <option> tags to a variable using loop
 }

}).done(function(){
 $.ajax({
   //ajax call to get current data. Compare and select data here. write your $.each here
  }).done(function(){
     $("#select_status").prop('disabled',false);
  });
});
```

You should be good to go now!!! I am sorry if I made it complex.

Comment: Hello Shubham, thanks for your help, to explain further : I have only one dropdown list which is listing all status available in my SQL database table INFO_STATUS, for example : `| Status_id | Status_desc | --> 1 follow-up 2 active 3 stable 4 etc....` And then I will add more through time. So I need to list them into the dropdown list when I update the profile of the company and also show the value the company has currently

Comment: If I am not wrong I need two SQL queries to send back to AJAX. `QUERY 1: collecting all data in INFO_STATUS` // // `QUERY 2 : Fetching the current status value in INFO_MARQUES` (cf. SQL query in my original post) and then compare both in ajax, is that a right method?

Comment: Yes you will need two queries, first to get all the status and second to get current status. You may first populate all the status and then get the existing value. once you populate all the values you can use the same code as above to match and select the current status. I know it is becoming complicated. I am adding a skeleton of code as an answer that you can check.

Comment: Thanks Shubham ! it does work and much cleaner than my code, I owe you big time

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that worked but not sure it is very clean though. 

For those interested to know:

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" name="select_status" id="status">
                        <option value=''>Selectionner</option>
                    <?php 
try {
                    $user = new USER();
                    $output = array();
                    $stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM info_status");
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result=$stmt->fetchAll();

                    foreach($result as $row) {
                        echo '<option value='.$row["status_id"].'>'.$row["status_desc"].'</option>';
                    }
}
                    catch(PDOException $e) {
                    printf('Erreur MySQL %d : %s', $e->getCode(), $e->errorInfo[2]);
                    exit;

}
?>
                    </select>
```

*We list down all options in my table into the dropdown list*

**AJAX**

```
$(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
        var user_id = $(this).attr("id");   
        $.ajax({
            url:"partials/test/fetch_single.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{user_id:user_id},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#userModal').modal('show');
                $('#comp_name').val(data.comp_name);
                $('#comp_parent').val(data.comp_parent);
                $('#status').val(data.select_status);
```

- fetching the right value from PHP page and sending to dropdown list so that this value is selected while opening the form (THE PROBLEM WAS HERE)

  ```
          $('.modal-title').text("Modifier un fichier client");
          $('#user_id').val(user_id);
          $('#user_uploaded_image').html(data.user_image);
          $('#action').val("Edit");
          $('#operation').val("Edit");

      }

  })
  ```

  });

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST["user_id"]))
{
    $output = array();
    $statement = $connection->prepare(
        "SELECT * 
FROM info_marques AS m 
LEFT JOIN info_status AS s 
ON s.status_id = m.comp_status 
WHERE m.id = '".$_POST["user_id"]."' 
LIMIT 1"
    );
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output["comp_name"] = $row["comp_name"];
        $output["comp_parent"] = $row["comp_parent"];
        $output["status"] = $row["status_id"];
```

*we return the match value*

```
    }

    echo json_encode($output);
}
```